# Can ASP.NET Web Forms App be used for visualizing data from Azure IoT Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-suite

I am building a POC IoT project and was analyzing various IoT cloud platforms that would suit the purpose.

Is it possible for Azure ASP.NET Web forms application to consume IoT device data read by Azure IoT Hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2016/03/30/presenting-data-from-an-iot-device-onto-a-azure-website/

Seems to do what you are asking for though it does run on Azure which might not be what you want.